# Tkinter unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, events, user-interface, loops, tkinter

I've been writing a long GUI in Python using Tkinter. One thing that I don't understand is why I can't bind events to widgets in a loop. In the code below, binding works well if I do it manually (commented out code) but not in a for loop. Am I doing something wrong?

import Tkinter

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()

b1 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 1")
b1.pack()
b1.focus_set()
b2 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 2")
b2.pack()
b3 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Button 3")
b3.pack()


def up_and_down(*buttons):

  for i in range(len(buttons)-1):
    buttons[i].bind("<Down>", lambda x: buttons[i+1].focus_set())

  for i in range(1, len(buttons)):
    buttons[i].bind("<Down>", lambda x: buttons[i-1].focus_set())

  '''
  buttons[0].bind("<Down>", lambda x: buttons[1].focus_set())
  buttons[1].bind("<Down>", lambda x: buttons[2].focus_set())

  buttons[1].bind("<Up>", lambda x: buttons[0].focus_set())
  buttons[2].bind("<Up>", lambda x: buttons[1].focus_set())
  '''

up_and_down(b1, b2, b3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be good, if you can add the error that is being produced.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that you don't use `"<Up>"` in your loop?

Comment: @pyfunc When I press the Down arrow for example, I get this error. Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1413, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "events.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    buttons[i].bind("<Down>", lambda x: buttons[i+1].focus_set())
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @Nathon Oops! In the second loop the event is supposed to be "<Up>". Sorry! But I don't think this is related to the problem. The answers below show what I got wrong. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your closures (lambdas) are not working as you expect them to. They keep references to `i` which is mutated as the loop iterates, and in the end all lambdas from the same loop refer to the same single last button.

Here's an illustration of the behaviour:

```
>>> k = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     k.append(lambda: i)
>>> k[0]()
4
>>> [f() for f in k]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: It's not really about lambdas, but about closures. You could define a function with `def` instead of a lambda in the loop, and the result would be the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem with:

```
for i in range(len(buttons)-1):
    buttons[i].bind("<Down>", lambda x, i=i: buttons[i+1].focus_set())

for i in range(1, len(buttons)):
    buttons[i].bind("<Down>", lambda x, i=i: buttons[i-1].focus_set())
```

Note the `i=i` argument to the `lambda` closure.